# MultiWidget Break in Template

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

I have created a custom SelectTimeDateWidget that used the default SelectDateWidget and a custom SelectTimeWidget

```
class SelectDateTimeWidget(forms.MultiWidget):
    supports_microseconds = False

    def __init__(self, attrs=None, date_format=None, time_format=None):
        widgets = (SelectDateWidget(empty_label=( "Year", "Month", "Day")),
                   SelectTimeWidget(use_seconds=False))
        super(SelectDateTimeWidget, self).__init__(widgets, attrs)

    def decompress(self, value):
        if value:
            value = to_current_timezone(value)
            return [value.date(), value.time().replace(microsecond=0)]
        return [None, None]
```

The widgets all work fine but because they are places next to one another in the form template it looks really clustered and not very user friendly. So I need a way to put a break tag 
 and maybe a label tag in between them. I cant find anything on the web(Maybe I'm not wording it right)

This is the code within the form template and both widgets are in that one tag so i'm struggling to think of a way to break them up onto different lines, Any ideas?

```
<label> Start Time/Date:</label>
{{form.start}},
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just overwrite `format_output` method from `MultiWidget`. It takes one argument, `rendered_widgets`, which is just a list of rendered sub-widgets. Default implementation just joins them, but you can do with them whatever you want. Example:

```
    def format_output(self, rendered_widgets):
        return '<br>'.join(rendered_widgets)
```

Or, if you want to write something between widgets in template, add this method to your `MultiWidget` implementation:

```
    def subwidgets(self, name, value, attrs=None):
        if self.is_localized:
            for widget in self.widgets:
                widget.is_localized = self.is_localized
        # value is a list of values, each corresponding to a widget
        # in self.widgets.
        if not isinstance(value, list):
            value = self.decompress(value)
        output = []
        final_attrs = self.build_attrs(attrs)
        id_ = final_attrs.get('id')
        for i, widget in enumerate(self.widgets):
            try:
                widget_value = value[i]
            except IndexError:
                widget_value = None
            if id_:
                final_attrs = dict(final_attrs, id='%s_%s' % (id_, i))
            output.append(widget.render(name + '_%s' % i, widget_value, final_attrs))
        return output
```

And you should be able to use `{{ form.start.0 }}`, `{{ form.start.1 }}` and so on in your template.

Comment: Thank you! This worked perfectly. I would also like to add a "Today" button that puts today date and time within the select inputs, how would i go about doing this? If you don't mind me asking

Comment: You should ask separate question for that. It probably will be made fully in JavaScript. Check django admin's implementation of that.

Comment: FWIW I think this is now different with 1.11 and its template based widget rendering. Sadly that stuff seems pretty opaque still—I can't figure out how to provide a custom template. It requires some changes to loaders that I can't yet find.